# Can we trust the impartiality of answers on Stack Exchange anymore?

Tags: discussion, answers, stack-exchange, quality

Stack Overflow Inc. has recently fired several high profile members and implemented policies that have caused many other high profile members to quit the network.

I am concerned that the quality of answers will suffer as a result of this, by slowly skewing the demographics of the network, especially those who moderate the sites.

In light of this, can we trust the impartiality of answers on the Stack Exchange network anymore? Is it a cause for concern that many of those who used to work on keeping quality high are now gone?

As an example, [in 2018 Ben and Jerry's released a politically motivated flavour called Pecan Resist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_%26_Jerry's#Political). A Ben and Jerry's employee might complain that politics has nothing to do with ice cream. That employee might be fired opaquely, even though they've demonstrably contributed more than most to the company's success.

In this hypothetical situation, Ben and Jerry's is now more outspoken on a non-ice-cream related topic, since the employee who said they should keep out of it is gone. They've also lost an (otherwise) excellent and valuable employee. Remaining and new employees are now expected to be more in line with irrelevant policy decisions, and be more extremist in one direction, or suffer the consequences. I don't see how this is good for the company (surely both sides of American politics eat ice cream, and potentially alienating a good portion of your market for a few gimmicky sales seems like a bad business decision). It seems to me that Stack Overflow has been doing similar things, and skewing the demographics seems like it would be harmful to the network.

Comment: I’m not following you. How is *impartiality* at stake here? The network never even aimed at impartial answers, we bias towards *answers from experts* instead.

Comment: Impartiality is great when you want to find someone to arbitrate a dispute or provide trustworthy advice when trying to select a what-have-you from multiple offerings. But the Q&A format doesn’t suit either type of discourse. It plays no role in questions and answers on the SE network as far as I can see.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the OP means that experts are leaving, supposedly (I'm not qualifying that statement here), and as such the bias toward expert answers will tend a bit more toward mediocre answers. As an example, I know a bit about programming, but I'm not going to provide a decent answer if an expert already gave a great one. Suppose many experts leave then I might be tempted to answer a question they would have otherwise answered. Clearly, that might lower the quality of the answers, so if that scenario plays out you can't trust answers as much. (esp. on more subjective sites).

Comment: @MartijnPieters think of it as having the luxury of going to well educated medical professionals normally, but being on a hike and just having a guy who knows first aid. You'll probably be alright, but you'd be more hesitant when they suggest doing more complex stuff. If they were your GP, you'd probably have trusted it though.

Comment: @JJforPopcornandMonica Or at least having the first aid guy supervised by a doctor.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm pretty sure (but the asker may correct me if necessary) that the question did not refer to some SO question where there are multiple possible answers with different pros and cons, but rather to sites like politics.SE, skeptics.SE, biology.SE or history.SE. I personally do not trust SE any more. Who knows what they deleted just because some director personally and subjectively didn't like it...?

Answer (score 6):

> In light of this, can we trust the impartiality of answers on the Stack Exchange network anymore? Is it a cause for concern that many of those who used to work on keeping quality high are now gone?

Well, the one actually answering the vast majority of the questions is the Community, and not (necessarily) the SE staff.

**The fact that Stack Exchange, Inc. is taking a new direction does not mean that the Community will do the same, thus it is safe to say that the quality of answers should remain the same.** (those members will be missed, though)

If anything, what *could perhaps* decrease is the maintenance of the sites, edits, flags, etc., given that mods and CM members play an important role there.

Comment: I wonder where this optimism comes from. The messages that have been sent out officially have been crystal clear. My guess is that at some point, truthful, science-based answers in categories like https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender?tab=Votes will simply no longer be accepted for ideological reasons.

Comment: They cant "fire" the Community. You are right that perhaps users may be less motivated to answer, but the change the **company** is taking is independent of the behavior and answer-quality the Community has. That's how I see it at least

Comment: Again, where does the idea come from that "the community" does play **any** role here? When there is an answer to a controversial topic, and the answer does not fit the desired narratives, then some director may force some moderator/manager to delete the answer. And that's that.

Comment: And where does your idea that it doesn't come from?... I'm sorry I don't get your point :/ the Community (the ones who answer) is one thing (actually, millions of people) and the CM and SE staff is another. They are related, yes, and our fates are bound to each other, but they are Independent

Comment: The idea comes from observing how they utterly ignored the community recently, and how they wreaked havoc in terms of deletions and bans. SE gained my trust in 8 years, and lost it within 6-8 months, but maybe the trust of others is easier to gain and maintain.

Comment: Yeah, you lost your faith on the SE staff perhaps... Many have done so lately... But, Have you lost your faith in the Community also?... Think about that (that's where mi point is going)

Comment: @DarkCygnus If the company shows willingness to chose who can be part of the community that is at odds with who the community accepts as a member, can you still have faith in the community?

Comment: @DarkCygnus -- "They can't 'fire' the Community": but they can drive community members away, and are already doing so.

Comment: Yes, but that does not necessarily affect the quality of the answers given. A bad answer can still be DV and a good one UV, edited, reach consensus etc... Of course, it's undeniable that eventually if this trend continues there will be a point where it will start to affect the quality I fear :( (when will that happen I don't know)

Comment: From the comments, as far as I can tell, it boils down to the question: Do you think that the company will ... "influence"... the community (or specifically, the answers that are given by the community) in some non-objective way? I'd say yes: They already *are* influencing the community, driving away people who do not share their (at least) questionable ideas. And at least on meta, we could already observe how "uncomfortable, non-obedient" answers have been deleted. There is no reason to assume that this will not extend to the core sites. People will complain about that, but will be ignored.